# Android Studio cannot resolve method SetOnItemClickListener (Java)

Tags: java, android, methods

I am trying to make carousel with clickable images, made as a list. I want to make so using SetOnItemCLickListener, but when I try to rebuild the project an error pops up and tells me:

> error: cannot find symbol method `setOnItemClickListener(<anonymous OnItemClickListener>)`

I searched the internet for a solution but I am still stuck.

I have tried so far:

1. Clean the project (obvious);
2. Searched for name illegal elements, there are none;

When I tried only with SetOnCLickListener it did not work; it is in red-colored letters and there is no method like this.

```
public class FinalSadMovies extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_sad_movies);
List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        imageItems.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.joker));
        imageItems.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.starwars_resized));
        imageItems.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.test));

        CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this, imageItems, 0);
        carouselPicker.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        carouselPicker.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "ListView item clicked.");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [carouselPicker](https://github.com/GoodieBag/CarouselPicker) from GoodieBag then `setOnItemClickListener` is not supported. 
The only thing you can rely on is the `addOnPageChangeListener` but this requires you to change your app UI and flow (because you need to use a button to confirm the selection).

Another option is to create a custom `CarouselViewAdapter` class where you can handle the click event on the `instantiateItem` method.

Comment: Well, thanks! Is seems that i have to make custom CarouselViewAdapter!

Comment: @DanielHristov please feel free to accept the reply in case it answers your question